# Clockwork recipe for Capistrano 3

Tags: ruby, deployment, capistrano3, clockwork

I'm trying to write a Clockwork recipe for Capistrano 3. After having a look at [Sidekiq's recipe](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/capistrano.rb) I've come up with this:

```
namespace :load do
  task :defaults do
    set :clockwork_default_hooks, -> { true }

    set :clockwork_pid,           -> { 'tmp/pids/clockwork.pid' }
    set :clockwork_log,           -> { "#{current_path}/log/clockwork.log" }

    set :clockwork_roles,         -> { :app }

    set :clockwork_config,        -> { 'clock.rb' }
  end
end

namespace :deploy do
  before :starting, :check_clockwork_hooks do
    invoke 'clockwork:add_default_hooks' if fetch(:clockwork_default_hooks)
  end
end

namespace :clockwork do
  def clockwork_pid_full_path
    if fetch(:clockwork_pid).start_with?('/')
      fetch(:clockwork_pid)
    else
      "#{current_path}/#{fetch(:clockwork_pid)}"
    end
  end

  task :add_default_hooks do
    after 'deploy:updated',   'clockwork:stop'
    after 'deploy:reverted',  'clockwork:stop'
    after 'deploy:published', 'clockwork:start'
  end

  desc 'Stop clockwork'
  task :stop do
    on roles fetch(:clockwork_roles) do
      if test "[ -f #{clockwork_pid_full_path} ]"
        within current_path do
          execute "kill -int $(cat #{clockwork_pid_full_path}) 2>/dev/null"
        end
      else
        execute "echo 'clockwork was not running'"
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Start clockwork'
  task :start do
    on roles fetch(:clockwork_roles) do
      within current_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env, 'production') do
          execute "export RAILS_ENV=$RAILS_ENV"
          execute :bundle, :exec, :clockwork, "#{fetch(:clockwork_config)} >> #{fetch(:clockwork_log)} 2>&1 &"
        end
        execute "ps -eo pid,command | grep clockwork | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}' > #{clockwork_pid_full_path}"
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart clockwork'
  task :restart do
    invoke 'clockwork:stop'
    invoke 'clockwork:start'
  end
end
```

However, the **clockwork:start** task only works if I remove the `2>&1 &` part at the end. If I try to start the process in the background, nothing seems to happen.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you make it work?

Comment: @emerak Have a look at the answer.

Comment: Did you manually create the pids folder?

Comment: Honestly, I don't remember. If it doesn't exist, you can create it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up with. I adapted it from a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/vjfrancois/9951002) I found.

```
namespace :clockwork do
  desc "Stop clockwork"
  task :stop do
    on roles(:app) do
      within release_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          execute :bundle, :exec, :clockworkd, "-c clock.rb --pid-dir=#{cw_pid_dir} --log-dir=#{cw_log_dir} --log stop"
        end
      end
    end
  end

  desc "Clockwork status"
  task :status do
    on roles(:app) do
      within release_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          execute :bundle, :exec, :clockworkd, "-c clock.rb --pid-dir=#{cw_pid_dir} --log-dir=#{cw_log_dir} --log status"
        end
      end
    end
  end

  desc "Start clockwork"
  task :start do
    on roles(:app) do
      within release_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          execute :bundle, :exec, :clockworkd, "-c clock.rb --pid-dir=#{cw_pid_dir} --log-dir=#{cw_log_dir} --log start"
        end
      end
    end
  end

  desc "Restart clockwork"
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app) do
      within release_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          execute :bundle, :exec, :clockworkd, "-c clock.rb --pid-dir=#{cw_pid_dir} --log-dir=#{cw_log_dir} --log restart"
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def cw_log_dir
    "#{shared_path}/log"
  end

  def cw_pid_dir
    "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids"
  end

  def rails_env
    fetch(:rails_env, false) ? "RAILS_ENV=#{fetch(:rails_env)}" : ''
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this gem [capistrano-clockwork](https://github.com/h0lyalg0rithm/capistrano-clockwork).

It's the most easy way that worked very well to me. I tried several options of 'gists' but no success.

You just need update this files `Gemfile`, `Capifile` and `deploy.rb`.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'daemons'
gem 'capistrano-clockwork', group: :development
```

Capfile:

```
require 'capistrano/clockwork'
```

deploy.rb:

```
set :clockwork_file, "lib/name_of_your_clockwork_config.rb"
```

Remember to execute `bundle install` before deploy ;)